# What's wrong with this Rust FFI declaration of CertOpenSystemsStoreW or CertCloseStore?

Tags: winapi, rust, ffi

I'm trying to call the Win32 API `CertOpenSystemsStoreW` and `CertCloseStore` functions from Rust.  When I do, I get an access violation on `CertCloseStore`, so I suppose I have the size wrong on some argument type, but I can't see it.

The following Python code works (and I have equivalent working C++, but not as nicely contained):

```py
In [1]: import ctypes    
In [2]: c32 = ctypes.windll.crypt32    
In [3]: c32.CertOpenSystemStoreW.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_wchar_p]    
In [4]: c32.CertOpenSystemStoreW.restype = ctypes.c_void_p    
In [5]: c32.CertCloseStore.argtypes=[ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_ulong]    
In [6]: s = c32.CertOpenSystemStoreW(0, "my")    
In [7]: c32.CertCloseStore(s, 0)
Out[7]: 1
```

Here's the failing Rust:

```
extern crate libc;
use libc::{c_ulong, c_int, c_void};
use std::ffi::OsStr;
use std::os::windows::ffi::OsStrExt;
use std::ptr::null;

type HPROVIDER = c_void;
type HCERTSTORE = c_void;
type BOOL = c_int;

#[link(name = "Crypt32")]
extern "stdcall" {
    fn CertOpenSystemStoreW(
        hProv: *const HPROVIDER, szSubsystemProtocol: *const u16) -> HCERTSTORE;
    fn CertCloseStore(
        hCertStore: HCERTSTORE, dwFlags: c_ulong) -> BOOL;
}

fn to_utf16(s: &str) -> Vec<u16> {
    let os_s = OsStr::new(s);
    return os_s.encode_wide().chain(Some(0).into_iter()).collect::<Vec<_>>();
}

fn main() {
    let protocol_utf16 = to_utf16("my");
    let storehandle;
    unsafe {
        storehandle = CertOpenSystemStoreW(null(), protocol_utf16.as_ptr());
    }

    let freeresults;
    unsafe {
        freeresults = CertCloseStore(storehandle, 0);
    }
    println!("{}", freeresults);
}
```

I'm using Rust 1.16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there were two problems:

1. DWORDs are 32 bits, no matter whether you're on 64bit or 32bit windows (which makes sense, I suppose).  So my CertCloseStore's second argument is wrong.
2. `c_void` is not a pointer type - it's just a `u8`.  So my code above should be something like `type HPROVIDER = *const c_void;`  (Which is not great, since it makes all HPROVIDERs const, but I don't see a way to do a Rust-style pointer typedef without also specifying either 'mut' or 'const').

Comment: Is #1 really true? In contrast to common sense and practice in other OS-es, `unsigned long` is actually 32-bit on Windows C compilers.

Comment: @user4815162342: yes, `DWORD` is always 32-bit in size, see [Windows Data Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751.aspx): "*A **32-bit** unsigned integer. The range is 0 through 4294967295 decimal.*"  The 64-bit version is `DWORDLONG`, and the platform-dependent version is `DWORD_PTR`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, but `unsigned long` is also always 32-bit in size (on Windows), so the signature of `CertCloseStore` is actually correct. The OP also reports Python code which uses `ctypes.c_ulong` to work, which is consistent with this.

Comment: @user4815162342: I wasn't debating that. I was simply commenting on your "Is #1 really true?" question.

Comment: @RemyLebeau #1 also contends that "my CertCloseStore's second argument is wrong". That was the part I was questioning, since the second argument is actually correct.

Comment: @user4815162342: if you go by [this definition of `c_ulong`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.6.0/libc/type.c_ulong.html) in the Rust documentation, then no.  If you go by [this definition of `c_ulong`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rust-lang/libc/master/src/windows.rs) on GitHub, then yes. Either way, I would suggest defining `CertCloseStore()` less ambiguously, eg: `type DWORD = u32; fn CertCloseStore(hCertStore: HCERTSTORE, dwFlags: DWORD) -> BOOL;`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Unfortunately the definition in the documentation is Linux-centric, as the documentation is generated solely on Linux. (That is a known issue with Rust documentation, which also doesn't document Windows-specific extension to the stdlib such as `std::os::windows::ffi::OsStrExt` used in the question.) I agree that a less ambiguous definition is better - I would advise importing e.g. `winapi::minwindef::DWORD` from the winapi crate. Having said that, I am still questioning the validity of #1 point in the answer; the crash from the question it is likely caused just by #2.

Comment: @user4815162342: Agreed.